# In Android Studio the input method editor can't follow cursor

Tags: android-studio-3.0

hey guys i have a problem, the IME can't follow cursor, look like the image
[image: problem image]

how can i do to fix the problem?

Comment: this looks a problem from windows or any ime program you are running, not something related to android studio

Comment: it isn't？in other program dons't like this，such as google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I just know how to fix problem, i download jie from oracle to replace the jre in Android Studio, it's working.
[image]